# Transformation of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

I am drawing a quarter circle using CAShapeLayer.On single tap i want to transform it by 90 degree.But when i do it,layer is transforming and is going out of screen.I need the rotation around the centre point.Let's assume the centre point is (100,100).
Here is my code :

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
//CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 100, (0), (M_PI_2), NO);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 100-50, (M_PI_2), (0), YES);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

CAShapeLayer* arcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
arcLayer.path = path;
arcLayer.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;

[self.layer addSublayer:arcLayer];
```

**Animation code :**

```
  CABasicAnimation *spin = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

        spin.removedOnCompletion = NO;

        spin.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

        [spin setByValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI_2]];
        //layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        [spin setDuration:1.0];
        [layer addAnimation:spin forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing happens because the layer doesn't have a size. You still see the path because it is not clipped to the bounds of the layer. The rotation is applied relative to the center of the layer but without a size that will be (0,0) in it's own coordinate system (same coordinate system as the path uses).

You can see what I mean by setting a strong background color (not fill color) and giving the layer an arbitrary frame. The final frame you want is very likely the bounding box of the path.

At this point you should see that the view rotates around the expected point. Now you can remove the background color again.

Comment: Thanking you.your answer is convincing.but can you please elaborate - if i am fetching frame from CGPath using CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path),i have to bounds which as same as frame.I mean frame and bounds of layer should be same.Why?

Answer (score 0):

try setting anchor point of layer before the animation. eg:

```
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

(0,0) is top left corner of layer and (1,1) is bottom right.

Comment: yes i solved it by my way.And you know,its very odd problem.I am creating path and setting that path to cashapelayer.you can see in my code, i am using centre point of UIView.Tha was my problem.It was taking origin as centre point.so whenever i was rotating ,it was going out of screen.I notice one more thing,when you are creating path and passing to cashapelayer ,try to set frame using CGPathGePathBoundingBox,it wont show your content in given frame.You have to set bounds(bounds and frame should be same) to layer as well.Why?i dont know.Please tell me if you are facing same problem.